Adding and aligning plot to spare facet at end of facet_wrap()
This is similar to the question here, but I am interested in how to add and align a separate plot to a spare panel that may exists at the end of a facet_wrap() call.
Currently I am thinking it might not be possible currently, and I would need to make all the facet plots separately, but maybe there is a way.
I made a reproducible example using the palmerpenguins dataset. I tried putting the second plot in as a grob, which worked but did not align the plot axes with the other panels and not sure I know how I could make it happen.
# if librarian is not installed, install it
if (!requireNamespace("librarian", quietly = TRUE)){
  install.packages("librarian")
}

# load packages
librarian::shelf(tidyverse, palmerpenguins, ggbeeswarm, patchwork, ggplotify)


data("penguins")

# make first plot
p1 <- ggplot(penguins, aes(bill_length_mm, flipper_length_mm)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~species, ncol = 2)

# make second plot
p2 <- ggplot(penguins, aes(species, body_mass_g)) +
  geom_quasirandom()

p1


p2



# make plots into grobs and insert p2 into the empty slot of p1
p3 <- ggplotGrob(p1)
p3$grobs[[5]] <- ggplotGrob(p2)

# plot new plot
as.ggplot(p3)


Created on 2024-12-05 with reprex v2.1.1

Using patchwork inset_element seems to work, however I'm not sure how robust it is if you make changes. I tried exporting at different sizes/aspect ratios and it held together.
I've plotted iris data as I didn't have the penguin data installed and don't really think it makes a difference to the functionality of the answer.
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(patchwork)

# create facet plot with some extra space so there will be room for axis labels on fourth plot
# move x axis label so its not hidden behind the 4th plot
pp1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~Species, ncol = 2)+ 
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(2.5, "lines"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(hjust = 0.25))

#create 4th plot
pp2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length))+
  geom_boxplot()

#get spacing from pp1 and apply to pp2 (in particular space where the facet label is)
pp2aligned <- set_dim(pp2,get_dim(pp1) )

#add plots, intuitively I thought the align_to should be "plot" but "full" appears better
pp1 +
  inset_element(pp2aligned, left = 0.5, bottom = 0.0, right = 1, top = 0.5, align_to = "full")


Created on 2024-12-09 with reprex v2.1.1

I'm sure there are more elegant approaches, but a more "manual" approach was the best I could come up with.
I created thee separate plots in a for loop by species (named p1_*species* (p2 was the same, except added a title). Then used patchwork to put them all together:
library(ggplot2)
data("penguins", package = "palmerpenguins")

#' Use assign in the loop to create a figure for each species
#' Note: needed to add in a title since the facet title will be lost
for(xx in unique(penguins$species)){
  assign(paste0("p1_", tolower(xx)), 
         ggplot(subset(penguins, species == xx), 
                aes(bill_length_mm, flipper_length_mm)) +
           geom_point() +
           labs(title = xx))
}

# second plot same as OP, but with title
p2 <- ggplot(penguins, aes(species, body_mass_g)) +
  ggbeeswarm::geom_quasirandom() +
  labs(title = "Body Mass by Species")

# add it all together in patchwork
library(patchwork)
(p1_adelie | p1_chinstrap) / (p1_gentoo | p2)


I also see you tagged cowplot, so a cowplot approach would be:
cowplot::plot_grid(
  p1_adelie,
  p1_chinstrap,
  p1_gentoo,
  p2
)

